# Solving this equation for p

Tags: inverse, approximation

I have the equation:
$$
t=\sqrt{\frac{m}{gp}} \cosh^{-1}{\left(e^{\dfrac{hp}{m}}\right)}
$$
Where $\cosh^{-1}$ is the inverse hyperbolic cosine, and $m$, $g$, $h$ and $t$ are positive, real valued constants, and $p$ is a non-zero positive real number.

I need to solve this equation for $p$, but I cannot successfully separate p. I have thought about making $t=f(p)$, and finding the inverse, but wolfram alpha *"cannot find the result in standard mathematical functions"*

Is this equation inseparable? If yes, then what method can I use to numerically approximate $p$ for a given $m$, $g$, $h$ and $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cosh(x)$ and $\exp(x)$ are almost the same thing if $x$ is large, so if $\frac{hp}{m}$ is large an approximate solution is given by the solution of 
$$ t=\sqrt{\frac{m}{gp}}\frac{hp}{m} = \sqrt{\frac{h^2 p}{gm}} $$
namely $p=\frac{gmt^2}{h^2}$. If $\frac{hp}{m}$ is not large, we may take such  approximation as the starting value of [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) and find an accurate approximation of the solution pretty fast. We may also improve such algorithm by considering that $\cosh^{-1}(e^x)\approx x+\log(2)$ is tight for any $x$ moderately large, hence a better starting point is:

$$ p = \frac{g m t^2-2 h m\log(2)+m t \sqrt{g^2 t^2- 4g h\log(2)}}{2 h^2}. $$

Comment: Even better: $$\cosh^{-1}(e^x)\approx\sqrt{x(x+\log 4)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Make the following change of variables:
$$
x=t\,\sqrt{\frac{g\,p}{m}},\quad a=\frac{h}{t^2\,g}.
$$
The equation can then be rewritten as
$$
\cosh x=e^{ax^2}.
$$
Clearly $x=0$ is a solution. If $a\ge1/2$ then $e^{ax^2}>\cosh x$ for $x>0$, and there are no more solutions. If $0<a<1/2$, then there is another positive solution. You should have to use a numerical method like [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) to find the solution.